# ERROR: function st_straightskeleton(geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.3, postgresql-10

I'm trying to calculate center line from polygon, so i'm trying to do  with postgis function st_straightskeleton but it is rising the error of function not found.

```
postgis version: POSTGIS="2.4.3 r16312" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" (core procs from "2.4.2 r16113" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.4.2 r16113" need upgrade)
```

i have tried this example but getting error

```
SELECT ST_StraightSkeleton(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 190 190, 10 190, 10 10, 190 10, 190 20, 160 30, 60 30, 60 130, 190 140, 190 190 ))'));
```

Error

```
ERROR:  function st_straightskeleton(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_StraightSkeleton(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 190 1...
```

Comment: Function requires sfcgal backend http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_StraightSkeleton.html. Do you have such 
http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#reference_sfcgal?

Comment: thanks, no i didn't have it. i will try to configure it

Answer (score 2):

You need the extension `postgis_sfcgal`

ex)

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal;
```